# Error When Adding HashMap to ArrayList

Tags: android, arraylist, hashmap

The goal of the app is:

- Get  all  rooms ( type, id , ratein  one  night  promotion...etc)  of the hotel by the link [here](http://api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/availhttp://api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/avail?cid=55505&minorRev=28&apiKey=cbrzfta369qwyrm9t5b8y8kf&locale=en_EN&currencyCode=USD&xml=%3CHotelRoomAvailabilityRequest%3E%3ChotelId%3E218097%3C/hotelId%3E%3CarrivalDate%3E05/07/2015%3C/arrivalDate%3E%3CdepartureDate%3E05/08/2015%3C/departureDate%3E%3CRoomGroup%3E%3CRoom%3E%3CnumberOfAdults%3E2%3C/numberOfAdults%3E%3CnumberOfChildren%3E1%3C/numberOfChildren%3E%3CchildAges%3E4%3C/childAges%3E%3C/Room%3E%3C/RoomGroup%3E%3CincludeRoomImages%3Etrue%3C/includeRoomImages%3E%3C/HotelRoomAvailabilityRequest%3E).
- Add them to a list view
- Sort  the  list  view  by  rooms's  type

I'm getting the error when I try to add the HashMap to the ListView.

This is the code:

```
package com.androidopentutorials.imageslideshow.fragment;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.androidbegin.jsonparsetutorial.ListViewAdapter;
import com.androidbegin.jsonparsetutorial.R;
import com.androidbegin.jsonparsetutorial.Url;
import com.androidopentutorials.imageslideshow.bean.Product;
import com.androidopentutorials.imageslideshow.json.GetJSONObject;
import com.androidopentutorials.imageslideshow.utils.PageIndicator;


@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public class InfoRoom
    extends FragmentActivity {

    public static final String ARG_ITEM_ID = "home_fragment";

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;
    ListView listview1;
    PageIndicator mIndicator6;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    RequestImgTask task;
    String message;
    JSONObject jsonObject;
    private Handler handler;

    public String id;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the view from listview_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.inforooms);
        // Execute DownloadJSON AsyncTask
        //sort="NO_SORT";
        new RequestImgTask(this).execute();
        listview1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        if (task != null) {
            task.cancel(true);
        }
        if (handler != null) {
            //Remove callback
            //  handler.removeCallbacks(animateViewPager);
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    public void showAlertDialog(String message, final boolean finish) {
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        alertDialog.setMessage(message);
        alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    if (finish) {
                        finish();
                    }
                }
            });
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    private class RequestImgTask
        extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        private final WeakReference<Activity> activityWeakRef;
        Throwable error;
        private Url url1;
        private JSONObject jsonobject;

        public RequestImgTask(Activity context) {
            this.activityWeakRef = new WeakReference<Activity>(context);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
            url1 = new Url(pref.getString("datedepart", ""), pref.getString("dateretour", ""), null, null, pref.getString("adult1", ""), pref.getString("adult2", ""), pref.getString("adult3", ""), null, null, pref.getString("ageenfant1room1", ""), pref.getString("ageenfant2room1", ""), pref.getString("ageenfant3room1", ""), pref.getString("ageenfant4room1", ""), pref.getString("ageenfant1room2", ""), pref.getString("ageenfant2room2", ""), pref.getString("ageenfant3room2", ""), pref.getString("ageenfant4room2", ""), pref.getString("ageenfant1room3", ""), pref.getString("ageenfant2room3", ""), pref.getString("ageenfant3room3", ""), pref.getString("ageenfant4room3", ""), null, null, null, null, null, pref.getString("enfant1", ""), pref.getString("enfant2", ""), pref.getString("enfant3", ""), id = pref.getString("id", null));
            System.out.println(url1.get_rooms());
            jsonObject = getJsonObject(url1.get_rooms());
            System.out.println(jsonobject);
            try {
                JSONArray json = jsonObject.getJSONObject("HotelRoomAvailabilityResponse").getJSONArray("HotelRoomResponse");
                System.out.println(json);
                for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Storing each json item values in variable
                    String id = c.getString("roomTypeCode");
                    String name = c.getString("rateDescription");
                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put("id", id);
                    map.put("name", name);
                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    arraylist.add(map);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        public JSONObject getJsonObject(String url) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = null;
            try {
                System.out.println(url);
                jsonObject = GetJSONObject.getJSONObject(url);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            System.out.println(jsonObject);
            return jsonObject;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            if (activityWeakRef != null && !activityWeakRef.get().isFinishing()) {
                if (error != null && error instanceof IOException) {
                    message = getResources().getString(R.string.time_out);
                    showAlertDialog(message, true);
                } else if (error != null) {
                    message = getResources().getString(R.string.error_occured);
                    showAlertDialog(message, true);
                } else {
                    //products = result;
                    if (arraylist != null) {
                        System.out.println("emptyy");
                        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(), arraylist);
                        listview1.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where have you initialized arraylist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to add an map to an uninitialized `ArrayList`.

Please make sure that your ArrayList is initialized first.

You can do this as a global declaration:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

Or you make sure to check if the arrayList is != null before adding items.

```
if(arraylist == null) {
    arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
}
arraylist.add(map);
```